# Im using javax mail , it gives this error. java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/mail/internet/AddressException

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

i have added the main.jar library after downloading it from the official oracle website. my code shows no syntax errors. i keep getting this error:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/mail/internet/AddressException
any ideas on what to do?

```
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.mail.Authenticator;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.AddressException;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

public class EmailSender {

    public static void SendMail(String recepient) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("prepaering to send email ya bro");
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "587");

        String myAccountEmail = "xxxxxxxx@gmail.com";
        String password = "xxxxxxxxxxxx";

        Session session = Session.getInstance(properties, new Authenticator() {
            @Override
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(myAccountEmail, password);
            }
        });
        Message message = prepareMessage(session, myAccountEmail, recepient);

        Transport.send(message);
        System.out.println("meshe lhal maalim");
    }

    private static Message prepareMessage(Session session, String myAccountEmail, String recepient) {

        try {
            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(myAccountEmail));
            message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recepient));
            message.setSubject("SHUUUUUUU");
            message.setText("ENSAAA");
            return message;
        } catch (AddressException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;

    }

}
```

Comment: How are you adding the jarfile to run your code? Are you running on the command line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably lacking the implementation JAR for the JavaMail API. Here are the appropriate lines from a Maven POM:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.mail-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.2</version>
</dependency>
```